# Order in the quaternion algebra.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $K$ be a totally real $\sharp$-field such that
$[K \colon {\Bbb Q}] = {\mathrm {odd}} > 1$. Suppose that $D$ is the quaternion over $K$ such that $D$ splits over all finite places and all infinite places except one.

We shall define the Eichler order ${\cal O}_N$ of level $N$ in $D$. Let $P(K)$ be the set of all finite places of $K$. For each $v \in P(K)$, we have the isomorphism $\iota_v \colon D \otimes_{K} K_v \cong M_2(K_v)$.

I guess that the following two facts ho

(i) the image $\iota_v(D)$ contains $M_2(K)$ for each $v \in P(K)$.

(ii) $M_2(K)$ is dense in $M_2(K_v)$.

By using these two facts, each isomorphism $\iota_v$ should be unique simultaneously for all $v$'s once one $\iota_v$ is fixed for a chosen $v$.

We consider $\Gamma_0(N) \subset \mathrm{GL}_2(K) \subset \mathrm{M}_2(K)$, where  the left-hand down indeterminate $c$ in $\Gamma_0(K)$ satisfies $c \in {\mathcal O}_K, c \equiv 0 \, \mathrm{mod}\, N$.

### Q. Is the multiplicative group of the Eichler order of level $N$ equal to $\iota_v^{-1}(\Gamma_0(N))$？

I guess the ambiguity will be eliminated by the inner automorphism